# What is the correct job title?

Tags: resume, job-search

I've been seeking Design Strategist positions for years. Product or systems design - bascally the jack of all trades, pseudo project manager/communicator between designers and developers/engineers who facilitates communication, out of their boxes ideas, and momentum.

But nada - I got nada.

Is there ANOTHER NAME for this type of position?

Like the mid person between designers and developers (website/apps etc) who helps bridge the nomenclature and vocabulary divide so things work more smoothly? Not project manager. Something less pay-money-to-"learn"-this-"methodology"-ish?

There has to be another name, because the requirements people want for design strategist are absurd - used to be you just needed to be well-rounded and smart - now you have to have a masters degree that confers upon you the title of well-rounded and smart (even if you're not) and, apparently, you can't be more than 22 years old because all wisdom is apparently earned in your teens now...  Is there another job title for this kind of position that can get me out of the pointless quagmire of design strategy job searches? Thanks

Comment: At the moment this seems to be mostly rant, and it isn't clear what the responsibilities and requirements are for the position you want to know the correct job title for. Could you focus on those responsibilities and remove some of the ranting against impossible masters vs age requirements?

Comment: If you are looking for a 'jack of all trades' role, it will inevitably have different titles depending on the company. Usually designers and developers don't have a mid-person between them. There will be a project manager, who may or may not be hands-off, but there is not usually a middleman who belongs to neither team.

Comment: Put on hold. Your actual job title is determined by your company. If that doesn't accurately describe what you do you can use your own description but you'll have to come up with one yourself. We don't provide a platform for those kinds of personalised questions. Your post is also more of a rant than an actual question.

Comment: Don´t take the requirements in job-ads too serious. The 22 year old with PhD and 10 year of relevant experience does not exist. Just apply anyway if you think you can handle the job description.

Comment: "I got nada" - don't write this if you want to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 4):

I think the role you're after might be a '[Business Analyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst)'

> A business analyst (BA) is someone who analyzes an organization or business domain (real or hypothetical) and documents its business or processes or systems, assessing the business model or its integration with technology.
>
> The role of a systems analyst can also be defined as a bridge between the business problems and the technology solutions. Here business problems can be anything about business systems, for example the model, process, or method. The technology solutions can be the use of technology architecture, tools, or software application. System analysts are required to analyze, transform and ultimately resolve the business problems with the help of technology